# Top View,Front View,Left view and right view help

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, drawings, technical-drawing

I have to draw the front,top,left and right views of a given solid objects without scaling them i.e freehand. I am much beginner in this drawings. So I am getting no idea of how the given solid object is break into top,left,right and front view. So kindly please explain all the basics of how to break the figure into parts of the engineering drawing with few examples (without scaling).

Answer (score 3):

When you have an object to draw, you must follow some simple rules to explain your drawing for anyone to understand it easily.

There are 2 example explanatory pictures below.

### **Example 1**

[image: Example 1]

### **Example 2**

[image: Example 2]

Hope these helps!

Comment: It's worth mentioning the Back/Front and Left/Right views of Example 2 are switched. Back/Front should be the "equilateral triangles", while Left/Right should be the right triangles.

Comment: Yes I noticed now. Should I remove the Example 2? Thanks for help!

Comment: And how to draw those drawing which a square base pyramid and a triangle base pyramid at top

Comment: We call these as Technical Drawings. You can use one of the CAD programs. Also you must include the dimensions.

Comment: somewhere i see that we have to use dotted lines, and i know that the dotted lines are for hidden  objects, but i actually don't get them. So  please can you explain the examples of objects with dotted lines in front or side views. Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth noting that there are 2 ways to layoit the views. The three rotation way and the one rotation way.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking in Engineering Drawing terms, there are two methods to generate [projections of an object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiview_projection). First angle projections and Third-angle projections.These projections are developed based on assuming how the object is conceptually viewed in a quadrant system. [image: Quadrants]

> In First Angle Projection we place our object in the First Quadrant
>   (see above figure). This means that the Vertical Plane is behind the
>   object and the Horizontal Plane is underneath the object.
>
> In Third Angle Projection the Object is placed in the Third Quadrant.
>   This means that the Vertical Plane is in front of the object and the
>   Horizontal Plane is above the object.
>
> These changes in the position of the views are the only difference
>   between projection methods.

([Source](http://www3.ul.ie/~rynnet/orthographic_projection_fyp/webpages/third_angle.html))

[image: Projections]

So basically, visualize an object being viewed from these different planes. The  Frontal plane gives you the side view. Horizontal plane gives you the top or bottom views (based on the angle of projection).

And visualization is the key to becoming good in CAD drawings, 3D modelling etc. It takes a bit of practice and imagination; but it's easy to get the hang of :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the object in front of you, then the face you see is the front view and if you moved your position to the left side, again what you see is the left view etc.

Then there are two systems : do you draw what you see after (behind) the object or between you and the object but this won't change what you need at the moment.

Comment: Please could you illustrate with some example figures? Thanks!

Comment: Match my description with example 1 in the other answer.